# Proof this function is constant

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

I have the following topological space:

$\tau= \{U\subseteq R: 1\notin U\} \cup \{R\}$

and the following application:

$f: (R, \tau)\to (R, \tau)$

I have already proved that  if $f(1)=1$, then $f$ is continuous.

Now, I have to see that if $f$ is continuous and $f(1)=y$ where $y$ is not $1$ then $f$ is constant.

How can I prove that?

Comment: What is $R$ here? The real numbers $\mathbb{R}$? Or a ring?

Comment: Are you familiar with what it means for a function between two topological spaces to be continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V:=f^{-1}(\{y\})$, this is an 'open' set, as $\{y\}\in\tau$, i.e. $V\in\tau$. By $f(1)=y$, we know that $1\in V$. So, by definition of $\tau$, we have $V=\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

You know that for any closed set $A$, i.e. a set with $1\in A$, the preimage is closed, that means $f^{-1}[A]$ contains $1$ or is empty.

So what is the preimage of $\Bbb R-\{y\}$ ?

Comment: I tried to use your hint and I wrote the following:Lets take $U=R-${$y$}$\in \tau$. As f is continuous, $f^{-1}(U)\in \tau$ In addition, $f(1)=y $ is not in U so $1$ is not in $f^{-1}(U)$ What do I get from here?

Comment: @Blanca: So it must be empty. Note that $U$ is not open, it is closed.